# find and replace with regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

i have following coldfusion tags that are not self closed. I need to find and replace them with `/` at the end if not closed. 
i have come up with this exp `<cfset([a-z0-9 ]+) *[^/]*?>` that find them all, but how to add `/` on them by find & replace.

```
 <cfset var1="#db_var1#">
```

Result

```
 <cfset var1="#db_var1#" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
(<cfset\b[^>]*)(?<!\/)>
```

Replace with:

```
\1/>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qK4rI8/2)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. i Miss, India